# Nginx: Different static files for different URLs

Tags: webserver, nginx

I have two web applications running on the same server, say, **app1 and app2**.

**app1** is the ROOT application, i.e. it will be launched whenever anyone hits the URL, say, http://example.com/

**app2** is another application, which will be hit when some one hits the URL, say, http://example.com/newapp/

I am using nginx as the webserver, and both web application have their own static contents (js, css, images) to be served.

for **app1** I am using the following,

```
 location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico) {
      root <path_to_tomcat>/webapps/ROOT;
      expires 1y;
      log_not_found off;
 }
```

this works very fine and the static contents gets served like a charm.

And for **app2** I am using,

```
 location ~* /newapp+\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico) {
      root <path_to_tomcat>/webapps/app2;
      expires 1y;
      log_not_found off;
 }
```

for **app2** the static content never gets served.

I tried searching in net about this, but not getting exact links for serving different static based on URLs.

Comment: The `+` in your regex applies to the `p`. Maybe you are missing a `/.` before the `+`

Answer (score 0):

The `root` directive can be used to construct simple physical paths where the URI forms the last part of the path.

You can map a URI like `/newapp/resource.css` using `root` to something like:

```
/path/to/tomcat/webapp/newapp/resource.css
```

Using a `root /path/to/tomcat/webapp;` statement.

If you must map the URI to a physical path that does not contain the entire URI, you must use another technique, such as `alias` or `rewrite`.

Personally, it would be more efficient to rename the directory and use `root`.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: thanks for your response. My concern is that "location <param>" <param> itself is not matching with newapp and in the access.log I am getting 404 for all JS and CSS